# How do a rename a file using the Google Drive API for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, google-drive-api

This seems like a basic question, but I'm well into my second day now :(

I'm using the Google Drive Ruby Api here: https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client but the basic file examples in the README appear to be well out of date. In particular, calls to `Drive.update_file` don't take anything like the parameters shown.

So far, I can get hold of an authorized DriveService:

```
drive = Google::Apis::DriveV3::DriveService.new
drive.authorization = Google::Auth.get_application_default(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'])
```

I can get a File:

```
file_id = 'string-of-stuff'
file = drive.get_file file_id
```

I can set attributes on the File object that look okay:

```
file.update!(name: 'My new name')
```

But, I can't figure out how to get the update/patch to actually work after that. The README suggests `drive.update_file(file)`, but that just explodes with a type error.

```
TypeError: Can't convert Google::Apis::DriveV3::File into String or Array.
```

Looking at the code, `#update_file` actually expects a `file_id` as the first param.

I've tried all sorts of variations based on the README, like:

```
drive.update_file(file_id, {name: 'New name'})
```

or:

```
drive.update_file(file_id, {title: 'New name'})
```

or (looking at the code):

```
drive.update_file(file_id, fields: {title: 'New name'})
```

or even:

```
drive.update_file(file_id, file)
```

which explodes with:

```
Google::Apis::ClientError: fieldNotWritable: The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable.
```

But nothing works for me. Has anyone used this library? Everything else seems fairly straightforward, but this is just HARD.

Comment: Hmm, `drive.update_file(file_id, name: 'New name')` (or the equivalent `drive.update_file(file_id, { name: 'New name' })`) should work, as should `drive.update_file(file_id, file)`. Are you sure `file_id` indicates a renameable object? ("Note that for immutable items such as the top level folders of Team Drives, My Drive root folder, and Application Data folder the name is constant.") Is the error for both forms, or just the last one? If not, what happens when you do `drive_update(file_id, name: "New name")`?

Comment: Hi @Amadan `drive.update_file(file_id, { name: 'New name' })` or `drive.update_file(file_id, name: 'New name')` both give ArgumentError: unknown keyword: name
from /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/google-api-client-0.14.1/generated/google/apis/drive_v3/service.rb:948:in `update_file'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, after much more trial-and-error, the ONLY way this API works is with a **new** `File` object. If you use `get_file` to get your `File`, then you end up with an object that has an unwritable id field.

So, this - and only this - appears to work:

```
drive.update_file(file_id, Google::Apis::DriveV3::File.new(name: name))
```

Sigh.

Comment: And of course, do not forget the magic `supports_team_drives: true` parameter to your `update_file` method if you're on a Team drive, or it will complain it cannot find the file at all. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

Just verified that the following works:

```
drive.update_file(file_id, { name: new_name })
```

You no longer need to create a new `File` object to update the name of an existing file.